# C++: Issue with a pointer

Tags: c++

I am attempting to create a poptart vending machine program and am getting an error in relation to what i think is a pointer. When the code is on the screen, i am not getting an issue however, when i attempt to build the code i get an error saying 'Syntax error: missing ';' before '*''

Code:

```
class State: public Transition
{
protected:
StateContext* currentContext;
public:
State(StateContext* Context);
};
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Cheers

Comment: where is the definition for `StateContext`?

Answer (score 6):

(Occasionally the C++ compile error messages can be a little cryptic).

You need to *forward declare* the class `StateContext`. Before your class declaration, include the line

```
class StateContext;
```

Then in the implementation of `State`, make sure that the class declaration of `StateContext` is included.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include definition of `StateContext` or forward declare the class `StateContext` and add header in implementation file:

```
#include "StateContext.h"

class State: public Transition
{
protected:
StateContext* currentContext;
public:
State(StateContext* Context);
};
```

or:

```
class StateContext;

class State: public Transition
{
protected:
StateContext* currentContext;
public:
State(StateContext* Context);
};
```

Forward declaration allows you to use a pointers or references to class being forwarded without including a header for this class as long as you don't call any method (or use its data) on such a pointer or reference.

Comment: any idea that when i add the StateContext file as so #include 'StateContext.h', that i get an error saying, 'fatal error C1014: too many include files : depth = 1024'